# Associate android actions (at least turn sound on/off) with calendar

Tags: calendar, automation

Is there an app for associating events with time. For example:

- If it is during event in specific callendars (say Meetings) the profile is turned to vibrate
- Otherwise switch to normal profile

I looked on [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) and it looks nice but possibly it is something free or cheaper.

Comment: Tasker or Locale are going to be your best bets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a free solution so I am doing exactly what you're looking for with Tasker.  When my work calendar shows me in a meeting it turns the ringer to vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few...

**Free:**

- [SoundManager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sound-manager/com.roozen.SoundManager)
- [Silencr](http://www.appbrain.com/app/silencr/com.shynnergy.silencr)

**Paid:**

- [AudioManager Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/audiomanager-pro/com.smartandroidapps.audiowidgetpro) $1.99
- [Volume / Mode Scheduler](http://www.appbrain.com/app/volume-mode-scheduler/com.webcipe.ModeScheduler) $2.99

**Edit:** Just realized you may have been looking for something more robust than just a sound profile manager/scheduler.  Chronos ($0.99) and Chronos Lite (Free) appear to do similar things to Tasker and are much cheaper but they don't have the best reviews.  I haven't used them but they may be worth a shot.  *(My 2 cents: Just get Tasker)*

Answer (score 0):

[locale](http://www.twofortyfouram.com/)  The best by far.  Well worth the $.  Nothing else is a question.